# PhpStorm: Vagrant SSH Session frequently time out (I guess)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, phpstorm

Whenever I connect to vagrant withhin PhpStorm (either by Start SSH Session:Vagrant at...) or by explicitly provided credentials, those sessions time out after a few minutes of inactivity.

Can I set them to be kept alive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameter this timeout connection SSH onto your Vagrant by options in Deployment config : *Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment > Connection > Advanced options > **send keep alive messages each***

Me I have 300s setted in this parameter and my connection not resetting and I use many console connection SSH open in same time.

This official documentation here : [PHPStorm Deployment Options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/advanced-options-dialog.html)

[image]